# Pearson's correlation in R with one column and undefined number of trials

Tags: r, pearson-correlation

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID     Vehicle      MPH
001      1           50
001      1           60
001      2           94
001      2           78
001      2           101
001      3           34
002      1           56
002      2           98
002      2           95
002      3           36
002      3           42
```

I'd like to correlate the MPH values by vehicle type, meaning I'd see a correlation matrix of three vehicle MPHs.    Is this possible?  If so, how would I go about this in R.  There is not necessarily the same number of data rows per ID nor vehicle.  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

data:

```
ID <- c(001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 002, 002, 002, 002, 002)
Vehicle <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,3,)
MPH <- c(50, 60, 94,78,101,34,56,98,95,36,42)
df <- data.frame(ID,Vehicle,MPH)
```

Comment: Correlation is a pair-wise statistic. If you you can't match up values from vehicle 1 to vehicle 2, then it doesn't make sense to perform a correlation. `cor(1:3, 1:3)` is different from `cor(1:3, c(2,1,3))`. If you need help choosing an appropriate statistical measure for comparing the different MPH values, you should probably ask your question at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure entirely about the expected output.  Based on the description, we need to do the correlation for each 'ID', so we `split` the dataset by 'ID' into a `list`, then `acast` (from `reshape2`) to 'wide' format after creating sequence column ("Seq") by "Vehicle" (the `ave` step does that) and apply the `cor` function.

```
library(reshape2)
lapply(split(df[-1], df$ID), function(x) cor(acast(transform(x, Seq = 
        ave(Vehicle, Vehicle, FUN = seq_along)),
        Seq~Vehicle, value.var = "MPH"), use = "pairwise.complete.obs"))
```

NOTE: There are many options for `use`, so it is better to change it to the relevant option that fits it well.